# Screen randomly flickering on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, display, multiple-monitors, linux-mint, asus-laptop

I have Linux Mint 19.3 installed on ASUS UX360UAK Laptop. The problem I cannot find a solution even after reading many other posts is that the screen (on the main laptop display or on the external monitor) is going black for a second or two and then back randomly. Doesn't matter if the external monitor is plugged in or not. I didn't find a correlation between the CPU or RAM usage and the flickering.

Thanks for an advice in advance - it's really annoying and the laptop is useless for serious work in this condition.

```
System:
  Host: ASUS Kernel: 5.3.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.5.0 
  Desktop: Xfce 4.14.1 Distro: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia 
  base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:
  Type: Convertible System: ASUSTeK product: UX360UAK v: 1.0 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: UX360UAK v: 1.0 serial: <filter> 
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: UX360UAK.317 date: 04/18/2019 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-7200U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Kaby Lake rev: 9 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 21599 
  Speed: 2665 MHz min/max: 400/3100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2665 2: 2983 
  3: 2947 4: 3066 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  resolution: 3200x1800~60Hz, 3840x2160~30Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.3.0-46-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless 8260 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: f040 
  bus ID: 02:00.0 
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-1: tun0 state: unknown speed: 10 Mbps duplex: full mac: N/A 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 179.06 GiB (37.5%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Micron model: 1100 MTFDDAV512TBN size: 476.94 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 179.06 GiB (38.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0 C mobo: N/A 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 249 Uptime: 6d 1h 26m Memory: 7.66 GiB used: 4.54 GiB (59.2%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 7.5.0 Shell: bash v: 4.4.20 
  inxi: 3.0.32
```

Comment: Does that happen only on linux?
Have you tried livecd of another distribution?
Looks like graphics driver is crashing, but that's a long shot...

Comment: I haven't noticed that behavior on Windows originally installed on the laptop.

Comment: Recently I updated the linux kernel -- didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Inter graphics drivers.

Try this drivers https://01.org/linuxgraphics

or

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/eb45d2e22afec7534f4a117d15fe6d89)'s an article how to compile Intel driver with GPU acceleration support.

There is very little chance, that kernel update will fix this issue by itself.